# JQuery - Attaching Enter KeyPress event to list items

Tags: jquery, plugins, autocomplete

I'm writing my own autocomplete plugin with jquery. The list items are drawn dynamically based on a json response. I have up/down arrow key code that works well on keyup event fired on the input field.

I want to add an enter key event to every list item. So, when the user is navigating through the autocomplete dropdown using the up/down arrow keys, an enter key press event would add the value of that list item to the input field.

Can someone please help? I've tried binding event to the list item

```
if (e.keyCode == 40){ 
    // highlight the list item
    $("li").bind("keyup",function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 13){
            // add value of list item to input field
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have been writing an autocomplete plugin for jQuery as well. If you're not too far in your project, [check it out](https://github.com/betamos/Better-Autocomplete).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$("input").live("keypress", function(keyarg){
 if(keyarg.keyCode == 13) { //Enter keycode
   $("WHATEVERELEMENT").append($(this).val());
 }
});
```

To expand on your comment here is a jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/csLVX/5/: {tidying up my code a bit!}

```
    <ul>
        <li>ITEM 1</li>
        <li>ITEM 2</li>
        <li>ITEM 3</li>
    </ul>
    <br /><input/>



   liPossition = 0;

$("input").live("keyup",function(e){ 
     if (e.keyCode == 40) { // down arrow key code 
        if (liPossition != $("li").length-1) {
          liPossition++;
        }
        $("input").val($("li:eq("+liPossition+")").text());


    } if (e.keyCode == 38) { // up arrow key code        
       if (liPossition == -1) {
            //if we reach min items do nothing
           liPossition = 0;
        } else {
            liPossition--;
        }
        $("input").val($("li:eq("+liPossition+")").text());

    } if (e.keyCode == 13) { // enter key code 
    //some code to proceed the form
    } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks! live() worked BUT there's a problem. This is what I'm doing:
$("input."+id).live("keyup",function(e){
   if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      // down arrow key code
   }
   if (e.keyCode == 38) {
      // up arrow key code
   }
   if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      // enter key code
   }
});
Enter Key works but it always returns the value of the first list item. I want to grab the value of list item that is highlighted by the arrow up/down key and insert that value in the input field.

The arrow up/down key doesn't work if I use live("keyup") on $("li")

Comment: O now I see, you have a list and you want the up and down arrow to return the values of the Li into the INPUT tag... i will make a fiddle

Comment: no problem, you also need to make sure you select an answer :)

Comment: Sorry but I'm new to this site. How do I select an answer?

Comment: at the top of an answer there is a up and down arrow this is used to give points or credit towards/attempting an answer however to select the correct answer, below the points box next to each answer, you will have a faded out tick press it and that will change to green.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use just bind, because the list items aren't in the DOM when that javascript is evaluated.

Look into using jQuery.live() http://api.jquery.com/live/

If you have `<div id='autocomplete'><li>...</li></div>` then you could call the live event like:

```
$("#autocomplete li").live("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 40)
        // Add to the input field
});
```

Comment: @john sorry, but I didn't copy your answer.

Comment: This is what I did:
$("input."+id).live("keyup",function(e){
   if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      // down arrow key code
   }
   if (e.keyCode == 38) {
      // up arrow key code
   }
});

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `live()` rather than `bind()` so that it works even when your `li`'s are dynamically loaded.

[The docs are here](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

I would also add a specific class to the `li`'s so you can use a selector like:

```
$('.my_loaded_selection').live('keyup', function(e){//do your thing
}) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
countries = ['name1', 'name2']);

//Номер активного элемента в списке подсказок
numActiveItem = 0;


//Количество элементов в списке подсказок
countItemsListHelp = 0;

// Создание списка подсказок
function createHelpList(event) {
    var event = event || window.event;
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    var len_key_words = target.value.length;
    var reg = new RegExp("^" + target.value + ".*$", "i");
    counter = 0;

    // Нажат Enter
    if (key == 13) {
        document.getElementById("select_list").style.display = 'none';
    }
    /* Перебор подсказок */
    else if (key == 40 || key == 38 && countItemsListHelp != 0) {
        alert(countItemsListHelp);
        if (key == 40) numActiveItem++;
        else numActiveItem--;

        if (numActiveItem > countItemsListHelp) numActiveItem = 1;
        else if (numActiveItem < 1) numActiveItem = countItemsListHelp;


        for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById('select_list').childNodes.length; i++) {
            if (document.getElementById('select_list').childNodes[i].nodeType == 1) {
                counter++;
                document.getElementById('select_list').childNodes[i].style.background = '#ffffff';
                if (counter == numActiveItem) {
                    document.getElementById('select_list').childNodes[i].style.background = '#fdedaf';
                    document.getElementById('search_field').value = document.getElementById('select_list').childNodes[i].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /* Поиск и вывод подсказок */
    else if (len_key_words && key != 37 && key != 39) {
        numActiveItem = 0;
        document.getElementById('select_list').style.display = 'none';
        code = '';
        for (i = 0; i < countries.length; i++)
            if (reg.exec(countries[i].substr(0, len_key_words)) != null) {
                code += "<li><span style='display: none;'>" + countries[i] + "</span><strong>" + countries[i].substr(0, len_key_words) + "</strong><span style='color: #b4b3b3'>" + countries[i].substr(len_key_words) + "</span></li>";
                counter++;
            }
        if (counter) {
            countItemsListHelp = counter;
            document.getElementById('select_list').innerHTML = code;
            document.getElementById('select_list').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
    /* Если поле пустое*/
    else if (!len_key_words) {
        document.getElementById('select_list').style.display = 'none';
    }
}

function selectHelp(ev) {
    var event = ev || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    document.getElementById('search_field').value = target.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('select_list').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: As you only post code, and no explanation, would you mind translating the comments as this is an English site?